# How to fix this "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have used to save some data i mongodb database by using this code. When i send to the data to the server using postman successfullt save data in the database. But in server console shows this error message and crash the connection.

**router file code**

```
router.post("/timeTableRegistration", function (req, res) {
    const newData = req.body
    // console.log(newTimeTabl)
    const newTimeTable = new classTimeTable(newData)
    console.log(newTimeTable)
    newTimeTable.save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
            res.json({ state: true, msg: "Data Inserted Successfully..!" });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            res.json({ state: false, msg: "Data Inserting Unsuccessfull..!" });
        })
    res.send("Success");
});
```

**model file code**

```
const classTimeTableSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    className: { type: String, require: true },
    monday: [{ 
        one: {type: String, require: true},
        two: {type: String, require: true},
     }],
});
```

Comment: found the error. I have delete the "res.send("Success") and works fine.

Comment: Exactly, you'll be calling `res.send` and `res.json` always and you can only call one of these. Voting to close as no longer reproducible.

Comment: Note that the exact same reasoning is fully described in answers of the existing question with the same error message in the title. When you ask a question you would have been suggested that question and it's answers as a duplicate. Please actually read those suggestions before posting. The other clear problem was not realizing that ANY code present on the "next line after the `save()` **does not wait** for that `save()` to complete. If you wanted something to happen **after** all the other operations, then in belongs in the `.then()`, or a chained `then()`.